# How can I reset this variable's value?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to solve [this](https://www.codechef.com/problems/MATPAN) CodeChef problem, when given a string, I have to find which characters are missing for it to be a Pangram, and then return the sum of the position of those. I'm really close, but my code has a flaw somewhere that I can't find. The add variable doesn't reset to 0, why is that happening?

```
import string
x=0
letters = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)

def finder():
  add = 0
  for j in letters.keys():
    if j not in text:
      add += letters[j]
      print add

for i in xrange(int(raw_input())):
  for i in letters:
    x +=1
    letters[i] = x
  text = list(raw_input())
  finder()
```

Comment: Yeah, the code runs well, it's just that the "add" variable never resets to 0 when looping, that's the only thing holding me from resolving this.

Comment: When/under what conditions is `add` supposed to be "reset"?

Comment: When it sums the value of the final missing letter of the input string, so that it can start again with the next input.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, it's `x` that's the problem, not `add`. You're initializing it only once at the top, but continuing to increment it for each test.

Comment: I love you glibdud, I just had to put the "x" in the second for loop, you're the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `x` needs to reset within the for loop:

```
for i in xrange(int(raw_input())):
  x=0
  for i in letters:
    x +=1
    letters[i] = x
  text = list(raw_input())
  finder()
```